# Not seeing SSRS 2016 exec proc calls in SQL Profiler

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I have a report that calls a proc to load a list of Ids (procLoadIds) and then a proc that gets all my data (procGetData).

I start a SQL profiler trace with the RPC:Completed, RPC:Starting, SQL:BatchCompleted, and SQL:BatchStarting events and nothing filtered. I then refresh the page my report is on, choose my parameters, and click "View Report". I expect I should see a call to procLoadIds and procGetData in the trace results somewhere but I don't... is there something I'm missing setting up this trace?

I seem to be having issues when I am passing a lot of Ids so I want to see the actual "execute procGetData" with the parameters being passed so I can run that manually in SSMS.

UPDATE: I started seeing this show up but only for the event RPC:Completed. is there a way I can see this when I call it (I thought that's what RPC:Starting might do), not after it finished (or more specifically timed out).

Comment: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqldownsouth/2009/08/21/sql-profiler-wild-card-filter-on-textdata/

Comment: Knowing how to filter results isn't the issue, the issue is my proc isn't in the results in the first place. I'm running it wide open for the moment to ensure my result isn't filtered out.

Comment: Had something similar happen yesterday. Alter your proc and add a return statement directly under the Alter statement and then f5. Then remove the return statement. Fixed my error yesterday.

Comment: I've been altering the proc a few times so that's probably not it. I wonder if maybe doing that for you caused the execution plan to be updated and that resolved your problem.